# Apple Script runs, but no saved docx appear (no errors appear)

Tags: applescript

This code runs, but for some reason no files are saved after running it and no errors appear. Ideas?

## AppleScript

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/abc/folder" as alias list
end tell

repeat with f in fl

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open f
    set theActiveDoc to the active document
end tell

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set filename to name of f
    set the_path to POSIX file "/Users/abc/folder2/" & filename
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    close theActiveDoc saving no
    set new_document to make new document
    paste special (text object of selection) data type paste text
    save as new_document file name the_path
    close active document
end tell

end repeat
```

## solution

> set the_path to (POSIX file "/Users/abc/folder2/" as text) & filename

Comment: Do you see Word doing any work?

Comment: Yes, everything works, except the save. If I use "set the_path to (path to desktop as text) & filename" It saves on the desktop, but not with the POSIX file path

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different route.  This solution bypasses having to use Microsoft Word, completely.  I've configured this script to loop through every file in a designated folder (assuming all of the files in this folder are either Microsoft word documents, plain text files, or rich text files)… takes the content of each file, and creates a new .docx file with that content in a new folder

If this code is saved as an application, you can drag files and or folders, directly onto this application's Icon, to be processed.  If this application is directly launched, it will ask you whether you want to process a file or files, or process a folder with all of its contents

```
on open theFiles2
    --  Handle the case where the script is launched by dropping
    -- file or folders onto this applet's icon
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFiles to files of entire contents of folder theFiles2 as alias list
    end tell
    repeat with aFile from 1 to count of theFiles
        set thisFile to item aFile of theFiles
        set thisFile2 to thisFile
        set thisFile to POSIX path of thisFile
        tell application "Finder"
            set fileName to name of thisFile2
            set fileName to (characters -5 thru 1) of fileName as string
            set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & fileName
            try
                set newFolder to make new folder ¬
                    at (path to desktop) ¬
                    with properties {name:fileName}
            end try
        end tell
        set thePath to POSIX path of alias thePath
        set theScript to do shell script "textutil -convert docx " & quoted form of ¬
            thisFile & " -output " & quoted form of thePath & quoted form of fileName & ".docx"
    end repeat
end open

on run
    --  Handle the case where the script is launched without any dropped files
    set sourceFolder to display dialog ¬
        "Would You Like To Choose A Folder With All Of Its Contents Or Individual Files Within A Folder?" buttons {"Cancel", "Select Files", "Select Folder"} ¬
        default button 3 ¬
        cancel button ¬
        "Cancel" with title ¬
        "withTitleText" with icon 1 ¬
        giving up after 20
    if button returned of sourceFolder is "Select Folder" then
        set sourceFolder to ((choose folder) as text)
        tell application "Finder"
            set theFiles to files of entire contents of folder sourceFolder as alias list
        end tell
        repeat with aFile from 1 to count of theFiles
            set thisFile to item aFile of theFiles
            set thisFile2 to thisFile
            set thisFile to POSIX path of thisFile
            tell application "Finder"
                set fileName to name of thisFile2
                try
                    set fileName to (characters -5 thru 1) of fileName as string
                end try
                set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & fileName
                try
                    set newFolder to make new folder ¬
                        at (path to desktop) ¬
                        with properties {name:fileName}
                end try
            end tell
            set thePath to POSIX path of alias thePath
            set theScript to do shell script "textutil -convert docx " & quoted form of ¬
                thisFile & " -output " & quoted form of thePath & quoted form of fileName & ".docx"
        end repeat
    else if button returned of sourceFolder is "Select Files" then
        set theFiles to choose file with prompt ¬
            "Choose Files" invisibles false ¬
            multiple selections allowed true ¬
            as text
        repeat with aFile from 1 to count of theFiles
            set thisFile to item aFile of theFiles
            set thisFile2 to thisFile
            set thisFile to POSIX path of thisFile
            tell application "Finder"
                set fileName to name of thisFile2
                try
                    set fileName to (characters -5 thru 1) of fileName as string
                end try
                set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & fileName
                try
                    set newFolder to make new folder ¬
                        at (path to desktop) ¬
                        with properties {name:fileName}
                end try
            end tell
            set thePath to POSIX path of alias thePath
            set theScript to do shell script "textutil -convert docx " & quoted form of ¬
                thisFile & " -output " & quoted form of thePath & quoted form of fileName & ".docx"
        end repeat
    end if
end run
```

This code may be a little sloppy and there may b a better solution but... It seems to work pretty well on my system running the latest version of macOS High Sierra